# C# form is blocked after creation

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a `Form` when a certain event occurs. I put this created `Form` into a static member of the class where it is created. I debugged the code and everything works fine but the Form stays blocked and the user can't do anything in this window. It just appears with a loading animation (see picture). So nothing in the opened window is clickable, you can't even close it.

```
class CallManagementObserver : CallObserver
{

    private static FrmIncomingCall frmCurrentCall;

    public CallManagementObserver()
    {
    }

        public void callChangedEvent(CallEv[] events)
        {
            foreach (CallEv currentEvent in events)
            {
                switch (currentEvent.getID())
                {
                    case TermConnRingingEv.ID:
                        // Incoming call
                        frmCurrentCall = new FrmIncomingCall(currentEvent);
                        frmCurrentCall.Show();
                        frmCurrentCall.Update();
                        break;
                    case CiscoCallInfoChangedEv.ID:
                        // User accepted external call on terminal
                        frmCurrentCall.Close();
                        break;
                    case TermConnActiveEv.ID:
                        // User is in call
                        frmCurrentCall.Close();
                        break;
                    case ConnDisconnectedEv.ID:
                        // Caller has hung up
                        frmCurrentCall.Close();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see above I wrote my own Form class whose code is here:

public partial class FrmIncomingCall : Form
    {
        Call incomingCall;
        CallEv currentEvent;

```
    public FrmIncomingCall(CallEv currentEvent)
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.currentEvent = currentEvent;
        this.incomingCall = currentEvent.getCall();

    }

    private void initGui()
    {

        Connection[] callConnections = incomingCall.getConnections();

        Address caller = callConnections[1].getAddress();

        lblIncomingCallSource.Text = caller.getName();

    }

    private void btnAcceptCall_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        TermConnEv termConnEv = (TermConnEv)currentEvent;
        TerminalConnection termConn = termConnEv.getTerminalConnection();

        termConn.answer();

    }

    private void frmIncomingCall_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        initGui();
    }
}
```

When I show the Form via ShowDialog() it is usable but the program stops (since this is what dialogs are made for I guess).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Nothing freezes, the program is running correctly.

Comment: Using a debugger, it should be easy to ding out where it freeze... In fact, when debugging with Visual Studio, you can use the command `Break all` from the `Debug` menu (`Ctrl+Alt+Break`) and it will usually show exactly where the problem is. Sometime, you might have to select the appropriate thread.

Comment: The thing is nothing freezes, the program is running correctly.

Comment: If you click on the form, does Windows display something like **This application is not responding**? which obviously tell that the UI thread is busy 100% of the time and in most case indicate that the application should be redesigned to properly use background thread so that the UI is always responsive.

Comment: **You contradict yourself.** You say that you can do nothing in the windows (so obviously the windows is frozen) and you say that nothing freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your application is poorly designed... It seems that you have no idea of what multithreading is and why you should use it.

If the application hangs forever, then either there is a deadlock (something like the dialog wait on the calling system and the calling system wait on the dialog).

As I have no idea what `CallEv` is and how it is intended to be used.

Well, if the calling system works and the UI is never updated, then obviously, you never let the UI have time to be updated because your UI thread is 100% of the time using the calling system or waiting on it.

That means that the calling system should probably be used from another thread and that you should have some communication between both threads...

It might also be possible that the calling system might be used in many different ways (as it would be the case for serial port and TCP communication) where one could use what fit most with his application.

Another problem with your code is that when you close a dialog, as far as I know it cannot be used anymore without recreating the dialog as the dialog would be disposed... So you would need to set the `formCurrentCall` to `null` and update any affected code. Alternatively, you might hide the form instead and show it again when required.

In any case, it is hard to help you because we don't have any idea of what is `CallEv` and other classes or events in your code. Also, we have no idea which code is executing when the UI is not responding (or updated). So the question do not have enough informations. In fact, such problem are way easier to debug using a debugger as it is far easier to see what code is run and which line of code take time to execute or even to see which code is not executed.

Comment: This is hard to explain, first of all: thanks for your time. CallEv comes from JTAPI, you may have heard about it - Java Telephone API. I "translated" the jtapi.jar library into a .dll with IKVM ([link](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html)) since there is no other way to work with our telephone system in C# here.